# Open cv Face recognition: What does the prediction "Confidence" or distance value really mean?

Tags: opencv

I am confused on what the confidence value returned from the OpenCV face recognizer actually means.

In a face recognition program I wrote using the open cv LBPHFaceRecognizer, the predict() never returns a value greater than 10 even though the label it returns is consistently correct. Is a value under 10 a high confidence level or low confidence level for the prediction? This is my first time using Open CV so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The confidence or the distance that the "predict" function returns is the Euclidian distance or the Chi-Square distance between the given feature vector and the closest feature in the training data (using KNN). the lower distance means the two faces are mostly the same.